# TypeError: undefined is not a function at MailComposer.returnCallback

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am trying to use `callback` function, Its giving me error:-

`TypeError: undefined is not a function at MailComposer.returnCallback`

Function defined like this :-

```
exports.sendMailMsg = function (templateName, locals, placeHolders, callback) {
    ......
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Error occured');
            console.log(err.message);
            callback(err);                
        }
        console.log('Message sent successfully!');
    });
}
```

Above function called like this :-

```
mail.sendMailMsg('ForgetPassword', locals, function (err){        
    if(err){
        console.log('from call:'+ err);
        res.render('error', {
            status: 500
        });
    }
});
```

Any idea on whats going on?

Comment: can you post the full exception stack trace?

Comment: I got the issue, there were 3 parameters & at the time of using i was passing only 2.

Comment: ok. now it makes sense.

Comment: But i am further getting errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825114/typeerror-cannot-read-property-subject-of-null