# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subject' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

I am retrieving data of Template collection from mongodb. so my problem is when i give a wrong `templateName` the program is supposed to catch a error. But it doesn't do so. program goes further & i get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subject' of null`.

How to handle this thing?

```
Template.findOne({ name: templateName }, function (err, template) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occured');
            console.log(err.message);
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            template_subject = template.subject;
            template_html = template.dataMsg;
        });
```

If wrong templateName is given, i want to return error to callback function.

Comment: You can check before line no:8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb-native (the client library you're using) won't raise an error if your find did not return any document.
Errors are reserved for connectivity or syntax problems.

Therefore you must test the variable existence before using it, something like:

```
Template.findOne({ name: templateName }, function (err, template) {
    if (err === null && template == null) {
      // no error, but no result found
      err = new Error(templateName + ' not found');
    }

    if (err) {
      console.log('Error occured');
      console.log(err.message);
      // early return to avoid another indentation :) 
      return callback(err);
    }
    template_subject = template.subject;
    template_html = template.dataMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check before line no:8.
As *subject* is showing null.

```
if(template.subject && template.dataMsg){
    // ok
} else {
    // wrong templateName
}
```